# Сделать красивый вывод подпапок в консоле?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Что нужно сделать чтобы скрипт вывел название подпапок в таком виде?
dir1 (1000kb)
— subDir1 (500kb)
——— subFile1 (300kb)
——— subFile2 (200kb)
— subDir2 (500)
——— subFile1 (500kb)

```
const fs = require('fs');

function scaner(y){
    let y1 = fs.readdirSync(y);
    for(let x of y1){
        console.log(x);
        let stat = fs.statSync(y + x);
        if(!stat.isFile()){
            let path = y + x + '/';
            scaner(path);
        }
    }
}
scaner('./');
```

Comment: нужно знать глубину рекурсии, и перед именем выводить дефисы в количестве глубины рекурсии помноженном, например, на два.

Comment: а как узнать-то  её?

Comment: `function scaner(y, depth = 0){ ...; scaner(path, depth+1); ...}`

Comment: `function scaner(y,counter = 1){
 let y1 = fs.readdirSync(y);
 for(let x of y1){
  let stat = fs.statSync(y + x);
  if(!stat.isFile()){
   let path = y + x + '/';
   console.log(``${counter}`` + x);
   scaner(path,counter++);
  }
 }
}
scaner('./');` не сработал